# How to return value to Objective-C using DLLImport (hiding UIWebView inputAccessoryView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to return nil value to Objective-C using DLLImport and MonoPInvokeCallback.
I'm trying to implement this solution [iOS 7 UIWebView keyboard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033292/ios-7-uiwebview-keyboard-issue/19042279#19042279) in Xamarin.iOs
I'm able to get callback using this approach [How to port "method_getImplementation" and "method_setImplementation" to MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127453/how-to-port-method-getimplementation-and-method-setimplementation-to-monotou)

I'm trying something like this. Delegate is called but IntPtr.Zero value isn't returned to Objective-c.

```
delegate IntPtr CaptureDelegate(IntPtr block, IntPtr self, IntPtr uiView);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof (CaptureDelegate))]
static IntPtr MyCapture(IntPtr block, IntPtr self, IntPtr uiView)
{            
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
public void SetImplementation(UIView subview)
{
    var method = class_getInstanceMethod(subview.ClassHandle, new Selector("inputAccessoryView").Handle);
    var block_value = new BlockLiteral();
    block_value.SetupBlock(MyCapture, null); 
    class_addMethod(subview.ClassHandle, new Selector("inputAccessoryView").Handle, imp_implementationWithBlock(ref block_value), IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

How to return nil to obj-c?

Comment: IntPtr.Zero is not a `null`, just return `null` i.e, `return null;` and set the  return type of your method to `IntPtr?`.

Comment: @SushiHangover Return type is IntPtr. But IntPtr is value type so I cannot return null

Comment: Make it nullable (`IntPtr?`)

Comment: doesn't work :(